# I can't retrieve multiselect items checked when I open it in a modal popup MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-multiselect

I have a result table in my view and when I click in Edit button a modal popup should open with form filled fields.

The issue is that the multiselect dropdownlist doesn't bring the items selected.

When I do the same using the view (without the Modal) it works. I believe the issue is in Modal somehow.

My View with Modal is:

```
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <h3 class="modal-title" id="editTitle">Edit Effect List</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            @using (@Html.BeginForm("Submit", "EffectsList"))
            {

                <div class="form-group" valing="center">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserGroupID, new { @class = "text-capitalize", style = "margin-top: 6px;" })
                            @Html.DropDownList("ID", (MultiSelectList)ViewBag.Categories, new { multiple = "multiple" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }

        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

My Controller is like below:

```
public ActionResult Edit(string Project, int ID)
        {
         var viewModelEdit = GetEffectListData(ID);

         var categories = viewModelEdit.UserGroups.Select(c => new {ID = c.ID,                    Groupname = c.Groupname}).ToList();

         ViewBag.Categories = new MultiSelectList(categories, "ID", "Groupname", new[] { 1, 3, 7 });

         return View("Edit",viewModelEdit);
}
```

Also in the view that I call this Action is like below:

```
...
<div id="modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog"/>
...
<script>

//Call for Modals
$(function () {
            $(".edit").click(function () {
                var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
                alert(id);
                $("#modal").load("Edit?Project=@Model.Project&ID=" + id, function () {
                    $("#modal").modal();
                })
            });

})
</script>
```

In addition to the code above I did more tests and found two ways to create the dropdown with the same list.

[image: Picture 1]

If you see my MultiSelectList is right. The values were properly set as selected but they are not rendering in the dropdown.

[image: Picture 2]

Comment: Can you share the code where you are initializing your multiselect plugin? Could be that the plugin may not be reflecting your selection; If you inspect the DOM, does the underlying `select` include the `option`s marked as selected?

Comment: I tried to remove the plugin and kept a simple dropdownlist and it didn't work as well...
I replaced dropdownlistfor by listboxfor and using listboxfor it worked. But the question still remain... why is it not working for dropdownlistfor???
Anyway... I'm using listboxfor ... thanks